# Cannot start Couchbase on Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, couchbase, fedora

I've a Fedora machine on AWS EC2 (Fedora 34 (Cloud Edition)), with Couchbase 6.6.0 on Docker (latest) and until yesterday it worked well.

From today (after dnf update) I can't connect to 8091 port.
I also tried do upgrade to 7.0.2, it does not work.

I started it with "sudo docker run -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 couchbase:community-7.0.2" but nothing, I can't connect to the console.

A netstat inside the container reports that only the port 4369 is listening.
The port is free, I can open a nc inside the container, so it's ok.

Any other docker container works well, I tried with Rabbit and Redis, and others

Any ideas?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when trying to connect to the console?

Comment: Connection reset, I remember, but I can say that the port inside the container is not opened, if I enter the container, netcat show only the erlang port and no others